# Screen reader is skipping menu checkbox

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

Here is the HTML: the part that it is skipping over is the input element. It will read the alt tag and the logo name but will skip over.

```
<div class="row topheader">
  <div class="col-12 text-upper-logo">
    <a href="home.html"><img class="header-handlogo" src="images/iconlogoOG2.png" alt="the Buddy Jane logo which depicts a hand holding a bud."></a>
    <a href="home.html" class="text-logo ml-2">Buddy Jane</a>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu"/>
    <label for="toggle-menu" class="menu-button mt-4">
     <span id="hamburger-icon" class="menu-icon"></span>
    </label>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Not sure if the css is important for it but here it is:
In my css I do have the input element display none but after it I have an input image displaying block so I'm not sure if that's what causing it.

```
    .menu-button{
        background:none;
        border:none;
        float:right;
    }
    .menu-icon {
        font-size: 3em;
        max-width: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        margin: 15% auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: transform .2s ease;
    }
    .menu-icon:hover {
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }
    .menu-icon:before, .menu-icon:after {
        line-height: .5;
    }
    .menu-icon:before {
        content: '☰';
        display: block;
        margin-left:7px;
    }
    .menu-icon:after {
        content: '╳';
        font-size: .65em;
        font-weight: 800;
        display: none;
        margin-top:11px;
    }
    #toggle-menu:checked ~ label[for="toggle-menu"] .menu-icon {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    #toggle-menu:checked ~ label[for="toggle-menu"] .menu-icon:before {
        display: none;
    }
    #toggle-menu:checked ~ label[for="toggle-menu"] .menu-icon:after {
        display: block;
    }
    input {
        display: none;
    }
    input[type="image"] {
        display: block !important;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translateY(-24px);
        transform: scale(0.5) translateY(-24px);
        }
        * {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` in your code has `type="checkbox"`, thus the CSS applied to it will just be `display: none;`. `input[type="image"]` will never match your input unless you change either the CSS selector or the input type.

The `display: none;` rule completely hides the element both visually and from the accessibility tree, which is why screen readers will not read it aloud.

If you wish to keep the input accessible yet visually hidden, one way of doing it is to apply the following rules to your input:

```css
.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```